# xsd - accept xml where elements exist

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like my XSD to accept XMLs that contain a defined list of elements - even if the XML contains other elements as well (in any quantity). Is it possible at all? if so, how?

My xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root-element">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="has-to-be-included1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="has-to-be-included2" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML that should be accepted:

```
<root-element>
    <any-element-in-any-quantity/>
    <has-to-be-included1/>
    <any-element-in-any-quantity/>
    <has-to-be-included2/>
    <any-element-in-any-quantity/>
</root-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat possible via the <xs:any > declaration, but there are limitations to how much  the declared/undeclared elements can be mixed up freely.

Check out this section of the primer, with examples: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#any

Note that you can restrict, or not, the namespace of the "un-declared" elements, with the 'processContents' attribute. For instance:

```
<xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

'lax' discharges the parser from the responsibility of checking beyond the XML being well-formed. Conversely, 'strict' requires the parser to validate against the XSD of that element, e.g. (not necessarily a great idea):

```
<xs:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"
       processContents="strict"/>
```

Also, for the namespace attribute itself, there are shorthand values that are usually convenient: ##other, ###targetNamespace, ##local, #any (default).

Last, pretty much the same can be achieved for 'un-declared' attributes with:

```
 <xs:anyAttribute />
```

To come back to my initial comment that there are limitation in how you mix them up, I was referring to your using <xs:all , which has constraints defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#groups .

Comment: thank you for the answer. Unfortunately its not possible to use xs:any in xs:all (I have to use xs:all because the order of the elements is unpredictable).